# jQuery-ui controlgroup textinput order changes on initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Whenever I attempt to initialize my controlgroup, it changes the order so that the textinputs are at the end.

Pre init:
[image]

Post init:
[image]

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="controlgroup">
      <label for="instrID" class="ui-controlgroup-label">ID:</label>
      <input type="text" name="instrID" id="instrID">
      <label for="instrAddr" class="ui-controlgroup-label">Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="instrAddr" id="instrAddr">
      <label for="dropDownFormat" class="ui-controlgroup-label">Format:</label>
      <select id= "dropDownFormat"><option selected='DEFAULT'>DEFAULT</option><option>OPT_2</option><option>OPT_3</option></select>
      <label for="radio-write" class="ui-controlgroup-label">Type:</label>
      <label for="radio-write">Write</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-wr" id="radio-write">
      <label for="radio-read">Read</label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio-wr" id="radio-read">
      <button id="addCmd">Add Command</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".controlgroup" ).controlgroup();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation shows that there is an 'items' attribute. In this attribute you declare what types are going to be converted into what widgets when the control group is initiated.

Example: input[type='checkbox'] will be converted to the new "checkboxradio" widget when the control group is initiated.

I'm not positive just yet as I'm trying to do the same thing as you, but I believe you'd need to add the element input[type='text'] to the items that will be consolidated into this control group. Kicker is that you'll also need to declare a widget type to convert the text input to also.

Without the element type input[type='text'] being declared, JQuery-UI parses all the types that are supported by default (a list of supported can be found here http://api.jqueryui.com/controlgroup/#option-items), and then whatever is left after it is done parsing just gets appended to the end.

This would be why the input[type='text'] are showing up at the end of the line.

Continue-- So I tested adding the input[type='text'] to the various widget types out there, and they make the control group look a bit funky. But if you absolutely need to you could probably get away with adding it to the 'controlGroupLabel', and then add a few custom CSS items to your input box.

So your control group jquery would look like this:

```
$('.controlGroup').controlGroup({
  items: {
    "button": "input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], button, a",
    "controlgroupLabel": ".ui-controlgroup-label, input[type='text']",
    "checkboxradio": "input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']",
    "selectmenu": "select",
     "spinner": ".ui-spinner-input"
  }
});
```

Wish JQuery UI team would add text inputs and all other inputs into control group capabilities.

Comment: You can also experiment with adding the text type of input in as an autocomplete widget. Then at least it would remain a text style input instead of a label style.

Answer (score 0):

Any JS errors in the console? Are you running out of room? Try removing say half of those elements for starters and see if you get same behavior.

Comment: I tried removing everything but the labels and the text inputs, but I am still getting the same results. No errors either.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old topic but I don't found an answer or that specific question elsewhere.

After a few tests I found the following solution.

Don't modify `.controlgroup()`. Just add class `ui-controlgroup-item` on your `label`s and `input type="text"`.

Regards,
Antoine